# Frequency based sorting

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given an array of integers and you have sort those integers based on the frequency of
their occurrence. Design an algorithm and analyze its time complexity. In case of ties the smaller
number should appear first in the sorted list.

Sample Input: 3,4,3,2,3,5,4,2,2,1,2
Sample Output: 1 5 4 3 2

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem...  Is it?

Comment: This is most definitely a homework question.

Comment: It is not a homework problem. This problem has a lot of practical applications like you may want to sort a list of words on how many times they occur (say based on their popularity)

Answer (score 3):

If extra space is allowed: go over the input and do a frequency analysis. Write it down in some hash table. That means, roughly:

```
for each x in input:
  if x in table:
    ++table[x]
  else
    table.insert(x)
```

Then, a simple Quicksort on the unique values, with the comparison function taking into account the frequency instead of the value itself.

That is:

```
function freq_compare (x, y):
  return compare(table[x], table[y])
```

Where `compare` is numeric for the frequencies.

Comment: I had thought about this but then we have to take care of collisions when using hash table. Also how will you do a Quicksort only on the unique values? You need to store the unique values somewhere while doing the frequency analysis.

Comment: If you have a normal hash table implementation handy, there's no problem with the collision. If the table isn't too small, the runtime of the whole insertion will be O(N). As for the unique values - they can be obtained by just linearly walking over all the keys in the hash table.

Comment: if this really isn't homework, download GLib. it has a nice hash table implementation you can use

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array and then we can easily get the frequency of the numbers because the duplicate numbers will be placed next to each other. As you get the frequency of the numbers insert it in a map with key as frequency and value as the number. Since map stores the keys in sorted order we can iterate the map to get the result.

Comment: This method fails if multiple numbers have same frequency, because the older number of same frequency will be replaced by the newer one in the map . **As for the same key (Frequency) , there will be multiple values (Number).**

Comment: @Abhinavkumar true it will fail in that case. We can fix that by having a map value as a vector of int instead of a int.

Answer (score 0):

First make HashMap,putting array element  as key and their frequency as values.
Sort them using Comparator based on keys and values.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Sum_of
{
 public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> sortHashMapByValues(
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> passedMap) {
List<Integer> mapKeys = new ArrayList<>(passedMap.keySet());
List<Integer> mapValues = new ArrayList<>(passedMap.values());
Collections.sort(mapValues);
Collections.sort(mapKeys);

LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> sortedMap =
    new LinkedHashMap<>();

Iterator<Integer> valueIt = mapValues.iterator();
while (valueIt.hasNext()) {
    Integer val = valueIt.next();
    Iterator<Integer> keyIt = mapKeys.iterator();

    while (keyIt.hasNext()) {
        Integer key = keyIt.next();
        Integer comp1 = passedMap.get(key);
        Integer comp2 = val;

        if (comp1.equals(comp2)) {
            keyIt.remove();
            sortedMap.put(key, val);
            break;
        }
    }
}
return sortedMap;
}
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
      HashMap<Integer,Integer> hs = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
      int a[]={3,4,3,2,3,5,4,2,2,1,2};
       int n= a.length;
       int c=0;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        if(hs.containsKey(a[i]))
        {
            c=hs.get(a[i]);
            hs.put(a[i],c+1);
        }
        else
        hs.put(a[i],1);
    }
     hs=Sum_of.sortHashMapByValues(hs);
    System.out.println(hs.keySet());
      }
 }
```